# In javascript , how to add line break to a large block of text after 6 words?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have following regex which adds line break after 80 characters
but i want to add line break after 7 words.

```
long_string.replace(/(.{80})/g, "$1<br>")
```

Comment: How do you define "word"?

Comment: group of letters. seperated by blank space

Comment: OK, how do you want to deal with non-words such as `OK,`, `non-words`, `cases?`, and other cases?

Comment: single word . just want to add linebreak after 7-8 blank spaces

Comment: Perhaps using a word character [`(\w+(?: \w+){6})`](https://regex101.com/r/bbk35w/1)

Comment: @AkashSalunkhe Ok, that should be simple then. You already know groups and repetition, seems like your only problem is about [distinguishing whitespaces](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html).

Comment: Is the input (i.e. `long_string`) HTML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this will work

```js
const long_string = "one two three four five six <script>alert('pwnd');<\/script> bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla";

//first replace html tags then add line breaks
const output = long_string.replace(/<([^>]+)>/g,"&lt$1&gt").replace(/((\S+\s){7})/g, "$1<br>");

document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Try `long_string = "one two three four five six <script>alert('pwnd');</script> bla bla"`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is using a reducer

```js
const long_string = "I have following regex which adds line break after 80 characters but i want to add line break after 7 words.";

console.log(addBreak(long_string, 7));

function addBreak(longstr, breakAt) {
  let n = 0;
  return longstr
    .split("")
    .reduce( (str, c) => {
      n += n < breakAt && /[ ;:,]/.test(c) ? 1 : 0;
      return n === breakAt ? (n += 1, `${str}<br>`) : `${str}${c}`;
    }, "" );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match a [word character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\w` in a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and add characters that you would also allow to match for example `[\w.,!?]`

Then capture in a group matching one or more times `[\w.,!?]+` followed by a repeating pattern `(?: [\w.,!?]+){6}` that matches a space and one or more times the charecter class 6 times. Replace with `$1<br>`

`([\w.,!?]+(?: [\w.,!?]+){6})`

```js
let long_string = `This is a test one two three. This, is a test one two three! This? This is a test one two....`;
console.log(long_string.replace(/([\w.,!?]+(?: [\w.,!?]+){6})/g, "$1<br>"));
```

Comment: This will not work if there are punctuations or other special characters.